# HTTP Status 500 - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin

I tried to start application on remote host and received the below exception

```
message java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.handleServiceException(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1010)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:548)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:203)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:290)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:995)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:849)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:633)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:799)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
    scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader$class.loadXML(XMLLoader.scala:40)
    scala.xml.XML$.loadXML(XML.scala:40)
    scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader$class.load(XMLLoader.scala:54)
    scala.xml.XML$.load(XML.scala:40)
    com.exo.AppUser.<init>(AppUser.scala:17)
    com.exo.OdaWebApplication.<init>(OdaWebApplication.scala:24)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.getNewApplication(ApplicationServlet.java:82)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.createApplication(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:984)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.findApplicationInstance(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:807)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:456)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

i tried figuring out the reason and checked some issues but it's still not working
i found some [information](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ru/2013/02/java-net-ConnectException-Connection-refused.html) about it, but it was helpless
i checked some issues like:

1. service not listening - catalina logged about listening
2. firewall bocked request - no firewall, no antivirus
3. user can't connect to server - it's running only in localhost
4. application don't work - correctly work from IDE

Application run correctly from IDE, and also before host restart.

I can't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You've missed the point. You *have* connected to your Servlet. That's how you got the 500 status back from it. *Something in the servlet* has failed to connect to something *else*, while it was doing some XML process.

Comment: asked - 2 years ago!
problem still not resolved, but don't push the older rocks.
"XML process", as you can say, was building configuration from xml. And mainly question is - What is happened with Servlet?

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose the problem follow the list:

- telnet the hostname and port from command line `telnet {hostname} {port}`
- If the connection is established it is not an application error, but network problem
- look you are not using proxy - if so you need to setup proxy for your application
- If connection refused either there is something wrong with your application and possibly with network either.

Answer (score -1):

Its definitely one of the 4 points you listed

OR

you are hitting the wrong port number?

Comment: port is correct. I'm change port to 8082 and backup to 8081. And i know that it's must be some of this reasons but it not

Comment: Did you try building a war file and deployig it to the server manually by copy/pasting it to webapp dir and starting tomcat? When run from Eclipse, it deploys apps in its own tomcat plugin directory which you cannot access if you accidently start the server from outside.

Answer (score -1):

if that is not in those 4 points then Can You check whether the server is started successfully. may be there is a chance of Java Core(.txt file) generation(tomcat/bin folder). so server will not be started perfectly and also there might be chance of corruption in deployment directory. you can redeploy and check.